# Android Studio Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl() doesnt have token

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I can successfully upload an image to Firebase Storage, but when I try to retrieve the image using storage reference and getDownloadUrl() I get only the images URL that doesn't include the token, without the token I cannot display the image, I tried googling how to properly retrieve link from firebase storage and it seems i did it correctly (for the record I'm trying to use that URL to save it in as a string in a Firestore field that contains a string that is the link)

example:
im getting this:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/XX/X/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/X/XXXXXXXXXXX

instead of this, which does work when i put get manually from the firebase storage on the firebase console

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/XX/X/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/X/XXXXXXXXXXX?alt=media&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

this is how i get the user to pick an image

```
    private void openFileChooser()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        activityResultContracts.launch(intent);
    }
```

then here
this is how i get the image uri

```
    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultContracts = registerForActivityResult(new  ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                mImageUri = result.getData().getData();
                uploadFile();
            }
        }
    });
```

and finally here
this is the upload file function

```
    private void uploadFile()
    {
        if(mImageUri != null)
        {
            StorageReference fileReference = storageRef.child("star_images/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));
            fileReference.putFile(mImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.    TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            db.document("stars/" + starId).update("imagePath", uri.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.starProfileLayout),"No file selected.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

(in my firestore database
the star has a field which is a string named imagePath

in my firebase storage
the images are inside the a folder called star_imageS)

i just cant understand whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `downloadUrl`, there is no need to use:

```
 task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(/* ... /*);
```

That's because you're only reading the reference of the image. `task.getResult().getMetadata()` returns an object of type [StorageMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata). Calling [getReference()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata#getReference()) on such an object returns an object of type [StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference) which returns:

> the associated StorageReference for which this metadata belongs to.

So it seems that you are running around in a circle since you get the reference to the image itself, not the `downloadUrl` which contains the token.

To solve this, you simply need to use the following lines of code:

```
fileReference.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        fileReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                Log.d("TAG", downloadUrl);

                //Update the downloadUrl in Firestore.
                db.document("stars/" + starId).update("imagePath", downloadUrl);
            }
        });
    }
});
```